# What's the difference between forge.prefs and localStorage?

Tags: trigger.io

In a recent version, forge.prefs was introduced. This feature seems very similar to the localStorage API except that forge.prefs accepts callbacks.

What is the advantage of using one over the other? What are the differences in operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of forge.prefs uses the device's native storage implementation, for example  [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on iOS and [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html) on Android.

The exact ramifications of this depends on the platform, but the main goal here is increased upper limits on the amount of storage - some devices also don't have persistent localStorage by default IIRC...